# I want opacity one when object:over in fabric.js

Tags: html, canvas

```
  canvas.on('object:over', function(e) {
    //I want change opacity of object on mouse over on object
  });
  canvas.on('object:out', function(e) {

  });
```

I want opacity one when `object:over` and otherwise opacity should be `0`

Answer (score 0):

If the context is 2d. Using context.globalAlpha will solve the case.

```
 <script>
    window.onload = function() {
    var canvas=document.getElementById("drawing"); // grabs the canvas element
    var context=canvas.getContext("2d"); // returns the 2d context object

  canvas.on('object:over', function(e) {
    //I want change opacity of object on mouse over on object
    //blue rectangle
    context.fillStyle= "#b0c2f7";
    context.globalAlpha=0; // Half opacity
    context.fillRect(10,10,100,50);
  });

     canvas.on('object:out', function(e) {
    context.fillStyle= "#b0c2f7";
    context.globalAlpha=1; // full opacity
    context.fillRect(10,10,100,50);
  });
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am export of fabric.js. But the canvas in fabric.js haven't object:over and object:out.
fabric.js have mouse:over, mouse:out, object:moving: doc address http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html
 when mouse:over

```
canvas.on('mouse:over', function(e) {
  var targetObj = e.target;
  targetObj.setOpacity(0.5);
});
canvas.on('mouse:out', function(e) {
  var targetObj = e.target;
  targetObj.setOpacity(1);
});
```